# Powerapps drop-down display Inputext aera

Tags: powerapps

I am a new to the Power Apps and I would like to put 3 an input text area when the drop-down menu choice is foo. Currently I have this expression: `If(Dropdown1.Selected.'Planet_TP_Java_F9',"3")`

Comment: I have code If(Dropdown1.Selected.'Planet_TP_Java_F9',"3")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask better questions that have a higher likelihood of being answered. I've edited your question to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Default property of the text input control to define its value when the value of another control is changed. For example, if you se the Default property of your control to

```
If(Dropdown1.SelectedText.Value = "foo", "3", "")
```

When you change the value of the dropdown between 'foo' and other values, you should see the text input being changed to '3' or ''.